# NetBackup exclude backup selection

Tags: netbackup, exclude

I'm trying to exclude some folder from the Backup policy; what I've seen is that you can exclude some by adding a file in /usr/openv/netbackup in the **client**. Is there any way to excluding in the server?

I don't want to the user to be handling this, I prefer doing it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've seen it: if you go to NetBackup Management -> Host Properties -> Clients

Select the Client.

Then Properties -> Windows Client -> Exclude Lists.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a unix / linux system, I am afraid but you have no option but to do it on the client by creating and editing a "exclude_list" file in /usr/openv/netbackup directory as far as I know.